Считать ли обращение общим элементом?
Ребята, нашему другу грозит смертельная опасность(,) и никто, кроме нас, не может ему помочь.
Ставится ли запятая перед "и"? Можно ли считать обращение общим членом?
Обращение вроде членом предложения не является.
Интонационно я читаю без паузы.

*Ребята, нашему другу грозит смертельная опасность, и никто, кроме нас, не может ему помочь.

В данном предложении обращение не является общим элементом. Предложения не имеют общего семантического или модального плана; кроме того, второе предложение имеет собственные знаки. Также дополнения другу, ему  упоминаются в каждом предложении.

В то же время можно задать такой вопрос: может ли вообще обращение быть общим элементом? Ответ дает Справочная служба.


Обращение не упоминается как компонент, объединяющий две части сложносочиненного предложения, ни в полном академическом справочнике «Правила орфографии и пунктуации» под редакцией В. В. Лопатина, ни в руководствах Д. Э. Розенталя, ни в «Правилах орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года.
Обращение грамматически не связано с предложением, не является членом предложения. Вероятно, это дает основание авторам руководств по пунктуации не упоминать обращение как компонент, «отменяющий» запятую. При этом и в академическом справочнике, и у Д. Э. Розенталя говорится, что объединяющую функцию может выполнять вводное слово, а оно, как и обращение, не является членом предложения. Однако это кажется вполне соответствующим принципу, прописанному в правиле: вводное слово, указывая на оценку достоверности высказывания, выражая чувства говорящего и т. д., относится ко всему предложению в целом, объединяет его части.

В то же время существует мнение, что объединяющий потенциал у обращения есть, но он проявляется в частных случаях.


Спасибо огромное за подробный ответ!
